# Set default timeout on a per test basis

Tags: nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I'm looking for a way to set the default timeout on a per-test basis.

I'm writing some end to end tests in nightwatch.  One of the tests requires hitting an API a few times to set up the initial test conditions.  Its necessary to populate some user data in order to run the test.  This happens in the before() method.

The problem is, before() will timeout when it hits the default timeout interval.  I've read the documentation for setting the global default timeout, but I don't want to increase it everywhere. How can I do this on a per-test basis?

Async Before/After
https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#asynchronous-before-each-and-after-each-
Setting Global asyncHookTimeout
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/master/examples/globalsModule.js#L20

The test code is as follows:

```
const { TEST_USER } = require('../../definitions/users');
const { TEST_USER_DATA } = require('../../definitions/users/data');

module.exports = {
    async before(browser, done) {
        // the default interval is here, but changing it doesn't have any effect
        console.log(browser.options.globals.asyncHookTimeout); // 10000

        const usersPO = browser.page.users();

        // get the user from the API to test with
        const testUser = await usersPO.getUser(TEST_USER);

        // post test data to the user
        await usersPO.postUserData(testUser.id, TEST_USER_DATA); // this will exceed the timeout.

        // finished with async test setup
        done();
    },
    // Tests

};
```

Answer (score 0):

One Way you can do that is setting browser.options.globals.asyncHookTimeout value in every test which will override the default value from the config file.

I hope this will help you.

Cheers!

Comment: I've used that method in JEST and Jasmine, but it doesn't seem to work here. The global value gets updated, but the test still uses the default. Here is the result:  https://imgur.com/a/8Bg3LRK